# What has replaced org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/ConnectionPreparer.class in Spring 5?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am moving Spring 4 to 5.

What I'd really like is to find a fully fleshed out Spring 5 app with MSSql DB access and a pom that has all the dependencies I need, that I can grab from as desired.

I can't find such a thing.

My current problem is that my existing app uses org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/ConnectionPreparer.class from
~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jdbc-core/1.1.0.RELEASE/spring-data-jdbc-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar

I can't get Spring 5 to admit that such a class should exist.  Where do I find it?